# How can I get each cell in a row in Excel to display its own address?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am having a lot of trouble getting each cell in the first row of an Excel sheet labeled by its address.
i.e I want:
A1 B1 C1 D1 etc.
to be the first row of my sheet.

I have tried the function =ADDRESS(1,2,4,1) but it does not work generically. When I copy the ADDRESS function from cell B1 to C1, rather than outputting C1 in cell C1 it outputs B1.  Can someone please help me figure this out? I feel like it should be very simple but isn't.

Comment: A different way is the `CELL` function like: `=CELL("address",A1)` for A1. You can copy it anywhere... but the address is absolute (the output is in a "$A$1" format)

Answer (score 3):

Use this formula:

```
=ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(),4,1)
```

[image]

The `Row` and `Column` functions return the row/column of the cell, unless another cell reference is passed as an argument (e.g., `Row(A100)` would return 100). When the argument is omitted, then they return the row/column of the cell containing the function call(s).

Comment: Thank you very much! Perfect answer! :)